# Why can't I wget from this address?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to wget from the "Download Now" link on this website but it returns the following error:

```
$wget https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/supervanish.1331/download?version=46330
--2015-09-27 19:13:53--  https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/supervanish.1331/download?version=46330
Resolving www.spigotmc.org (www.spigotmc.org)... 198.41.204.94, 198.41.205.94, 2400:cb00:2048:1::c629:cd5e, ...
Connecting to www.spigotmc.org (www.spigotmc.org)|198.41.204.94|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2015-09-27 19:13:53 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.
```

Here is the page:

https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/supervanish.1331

Here is the URL:

https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/supervanish.1331/download?version=46330

Comment: It is because there is enabled Cloudflare protection (https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=iuam) which is checking web browser... Maybe you can try to fake user-agent header...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wget because the server returns an error.

If you want to retrieve an error page, perhaps [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/253826/how-to-use-wget-to-download-http-error-pages) will help you.

Comment: Open debug tools in your browser and watch the status there. It is still 503. Surprisingly, error pages are web pages too.